# Instantiation attempted on a non-constructor

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, instantiation

I'm trying to make a bomb catching game (I'm actually using the code from the AS3 Classroom in a Book on arrays). As soon as I changed the word fruit to bomb in the code I got error 1007. With the exception of changing basket_mc to eod_mc and fruit to bomb (I used command-F and replaced with case sensitive on) I haven't changed much. It worked with eod_mc, but doesn't with bomb.

```
var bombArray:Array = new Array(bomb);
var bombsOnstage:Array = new Array();
var bombsCollected:int = 0;
var bombsLost:int = 0;
for (var i:int = 0; i<20; i++) {
var pickBomb = bombArray[int(Math.random() * bombArray.length)];
var bomb:MovieClip = new pickBomb();
addChild(bomb);
bomb.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth-bomb.width;// bomb.width is subtracted from the random x position to elimate the slight possibility that a clip will be placed offstage on the right.
bomb.y = Math.random() * -500;
bomb.speed = Math.random() * 15 + 5;
bombsOnstage.push(bomb);
}
eod_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragEod);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dragStop);
function dragEod(e:Event):void {
eod_mc.startDrag();
}
function dragStop(e:Event):void {
eod_mc.stopDrag();
}
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, catchBomb);
function catchBomb(e:Event):void {
for (var i:int = bombsOnstage.length-1; i > -1; i--) {
    var currentBomb:MovieClip = bombsOnstage[i];
    currentBomb.y +=  currentBomb.speed;
    if (currentBomb.y > stage.stageHeight - currentBomb.height) {
        currentBomb.y = 0 - currentBomb.height;
        bombsLost++;
        field2_txt.text = "Total Bombs Detonated: " + bombsLost;
    }
    if (currentBomb.hitTestObject(eod_mc)) {
        bombsCollected++;
        removeChild(currentBomb);
        bombsOnstage.splice(i,1);
        field1_txt.text = "Total Bombs Caught: " + bombsCollected;
        if (bombsCollected >= 20) {
            eod_mc.gotoAndStop(20);
        } else if (bombsCollected > 15) {
            eod_mc.gotoAndStop(15);
        } else if (bombsCollected>10) {
            eod_mc.gotoAndStop(10);
        } else if (bombsCollected>5) {
            eod_mc.gotoAndStop(5);
        }
    }
}
    if (bombsOnstage.length <= 0) {
    field1_txt.text = "You Win! You have defused the bombs.";
    field2_txt.text = "";
    stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, catchBomb);
}
if (bombsLost >= 20) {
    field1_txt.text = "Sorry you lose. You have lost your foot!";
    field2_txt.text = "";
    stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, catchBomb);
    for (var j:int = bombsOnstage.length-1; j > -1; j--) {
        currentBomb = bombsOnstage[j];
        removeChild(currentBomb);
        bombsOnstage.splice(j,1);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: You should actually spend some time learning what this actually does, instead of just blindly copying from a book...

Comment: Well consider that my final is due this week, we had a substitute teaching arrays and oh yeah they shoe-horned this class into seven weeks. This happens to be the only thing I haven't been able to figure out on my own. I would appreciate some help.

Comment: Do you have a class called 'pickBomb'? You are trying to create an instance of one (Which invokes its *constructor*) I suspect this is where your error comes from.

Comment: Doesn't the line:

    var pickBomb = bombArray[int(Math.random() * bombArray.length)];

create that? (I'm think the instructor obviously failed to go over this thoroughly)

Comment: @DollahBill NO, you have to make a class file (*.as3) or a movie clip with the same name that will be your class name, and use that name to get new instances. `pickBomb` is a variable and is an array, not a class, thus no instantiation of `new pickBomb()` is possible. And Quirliom is right, you are trying to [cargo code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) which is not a way to actually do something useful.

Comment: @Vesper
Thanks, I appreciate the help. I realize that this is not the way to go about learning this. I have actually read up on everything else (mostly on this sight) and figured it out from there. I have spent on average about 40 hours a week on homework for this class, mostly because I have not taken any programming courses yet and I had to search for answers. I just had no clue as to what the error meant. I've seen several tutorials on creating classes, I'll check one of those (no we weren't shown that either). Once again I really appreciate the help from both of you.

Comment: @DollahBill Having no basics of programming, variables, classes and objects and other stuff is really hard, you need this knowledge constantly while you make your program(s). Make sure you've got these covered ASAP, because you will only be able to copy&paste without understanding or cargo code without knowing how does code ever work. Pity, I've got my programming education starting from algorithms instead of writing code, as you are apparently being taught. This let me to learn AS3 without extra hassle.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe to avoid making your programming life more twisted than it is now...

There are objects and classes in programming, a *class* is a description of a set of objects, say "table" (or, as it's better to differ in names for classes and variables, "Table", first letter capitalized) is a name of a class. An *instance* or an *object* is a structure that belongs to one or more classes, with `Object` being the topmost, as everything in programming is either an object or a "simple variable", that is, a number, a true/false, a string of characters (these are object types in AS3 too, though, `Number`, `Boolean`, `String`, but these generally not need to be instantiated via `new`) or probably some other simple type I don't remember right now.

Classes have *properties* and *methods*. A property is something that can be requested off any object of the class, say "height" for tables. Properties can be of any type, including nested objects, depending on what your base class is. Say `stage` in AS3 is a property of any `DisplayObject` which is used to get the only `Stage` object there is at runtime[1]. Methods are what any object of a class can be told to do. Say, bombs fall, explode, `MovieClip`s can be told to `stop()`, etc. You write class code keeping in mind that all of the objects of this class will have to behave exactly like you've written, but since they can differ in properties, you can give them conditional behavior. For example, if a bomb has already exploded, it cannot blow up once more.

A *variable*, whether a property or a standalone var (if you declare one in a function) is a reference to an object of a given type. Say `var i:int` refers to some kind of an integer. Simple type vars are containers instead, that is, `i=2;` will place a 2 in the referred integer, and `i=j;` will copy the value from `j` into `i`, while `var theStage:Stage=this.stage` will instead create a reference to an existing object, and if that object will change, the reference will give you the changed object instead of its previous state. An array is a collection of variables, reachable by indexes, in AS3 they don't have to be of one type, and a `Vector` is a typed array.

Next, the lifetime of objects. An object only lives while there's an active reference to it, whether in a property of another alive object, or in a visible variable, or in an event listener (AS3 specific). An object is created via `new ClassName(<parameters>)`, lives while you can reach it somehow, and is destroyed once you have no active links to it and Flash player decides to run garbage collector. Prior to this programmers had to deallocate objects themselves, a rudiment can be seen at `BitmapData.dispose()`. So, in order to avoid Flash player to run out of free memory, take full control over creation and destruction of links. You don't need to care for simple vars, they are being cared for by Flash player.

A lot of basic functions for interactions has already been implemented in AS3, look for them and examples of how they work in [Adobe's manual](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/package-detail.html), navigate through packages in the lower left, most of the interactive stuff is in `flash.display` package, refer to other packages as necessary.

Hope this will bring you some insight into programming basics.

[1]: There is one stage unless you're doing a load of an SWF, then there could be more, one Stage per one SWF.

Comment: Thank you. The course name was Flash, I was unaware (until the first night of class) that there was a pre-req of Programming Logic. My adviser approached me about taking the course, apparently she spaced it on the pre-req too. It's not even part of my degree, I'm going for graphic/web design this is part of the game design degree. So FML for taking a course I don't need and wasn't prepared for. Til this little hiccup I was acing it though, the instructor is aware that I'm behind the eight ball and has been a huge help. Thanks for the extra bit on basic programming knowledge too.

Comment: See, programming logic as is is needed in more than just getting a degree, but it has its applications in common life too, just watch more closely. And yes, even if you do your best design it won't start to play by itself, you will need logic to animate it, at least its basics.